# pass environment variable to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I used dotenv where I can store my credential in a .env file and access it via process.env.var in my server side. But sometime I need to pass it to the frontend too, like in my js webapp I need to pass my api url, how do I do that? I can store another set at the frontend but I think that's redundant. For now I'm just hardcoded them.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Why would you need that? Your API must be completely unaware of any one consuming its public resources and justa accept the data sent to id to validate the private ones. You may be allowing sensitive information exposed if you need to know the environment.